# Component does not implement lightning:actionOverride interface - false positive

Tags: salesforcedx, metadata, cicd

Today I started encountering this issue when deploying source code to sandbox using sfdx:

```
TYPE   FILE                                NAME          PROBLEM
─────  ──────────────────────────────────  ────────────  ────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────
Error  target/                                           Unable to build Bundle source
Error  target/                                           Unable to build Bundle source
Error  target/                                           Unable to build Bundle source
Error  target/                                           Unable to build Bundle source
Error  target/objects/Custom_Object__c.object  Custom_Object__c NewCustomActionWrapper component does not implement lightning:actionOverride interface.
Error  target/objects/Custom_Object__c.object  Custom_Object__c NewCustomAction component does not implement lightning:actionOverride interface.
```

Listed components ofc implements this interface, and they work perfectly fine for a long time.
Do you have any idea why it could be and how to fix/avoid those errors?

Answer (score 2):

I also ran into this today when deploying a flexipage with 2 new Aura components in them.  I found the following workaround:

- Deploy just the new Aura component plus anything it depends on (child component, apex controller, etc)
- retry the full deployment

Not an ideal solution of course, but it does seem to make it get past the hiccup.  You might also be able to manually create a bare-bones Aura component with the same name and the necessary interfaces defined and then let your deployment do the full update and update the aura definition.

On a possibly-related note, this was the first deployment into a Winter '22 sandbox, so wondering if the update might have caused our woes

Comment: Exactly, I think the same it's related to Winter `22, I deploy code to this sandbox for validation purposes, it's an empty sandbox (no metadata) I always do check-only deployment of full source code.